# Read Song Info Using Tasker

Tags: tasker, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I'm looking for a way to have Tasker read the currently playing song title and artist out loud or flash it on the screen. I have the output part down (using 'Say' and/or 'Flash') but I'm having trouble getting the song info. I typically use Pandora (so I'd accept if the task only worked on Pandora), but also using Spotify.

I have tried both %MTRACK and %NTITLE, (neither of which ever seem to be set), and Media Utilities. Doing this entirely with Tasker and Secure Setting would be preferable (I'd rather not download a whole bunch of other apps/plugins). Also, the device is not rooted, and I'd rather not have to root it just for this.

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 running the stock Android Lollipop OS.

[image]

Comment: Is the device rooted? You can grep string from the output of `dumpsys media_session`. The description there would give you the song name, song's artist and other meta info. Alternatively, on a Tasker subreddit I learned that AutoNotification app can receive current notifications, so that may help too.

Comment: Another way is to find the opened music files using the command `dumpsys  media.player` and find them in the output of `content query --uri content://media/external/audio/media`. You would get all the information you need. The cost is, you need root access and `media.player` doesn't work for all the music players. An alternative for that can be `lsof`.

Comment: @Firelord, The device is not rooted, and I'd rather not root it, especially for something that might not work.